# PUT mappings API overriding the exsisting mappings in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I have created an index template, where I am defining an "ignore_above" mapping parameter for a "keyword" field type.

Now I want to update the mappings and want to add a new parameter "eager_global_ordinals" for the same "keyword" field using the PUT mappings API,

I can see the API returning 200OK.

So to verify the mapping when I call GET index-name, I can see the new mappings "eager_global_ordinals", but not able to see "ignore_above"?

I checked, and found out that "ignore_above" property is getting overrided with default value?

Meaning PUT mappings API overriding the mappings parameter to default value, if i dont pass any.

is there any way to avoid this behavior?

Commands I have tried in sequence:

```
PUT /_index_template/example_template
{
   "index_patterns": [
        "example*"
    ],
    "priority": 1,
    "template": {
        "aliases": {
            "example":{}
        },
    "mappings": {
      "_source":
      {"enabled": false},
      "properties": {
       "SomeID":
        { "type": "keyword", "index" : true,"store":true,"ignore_above":5}
      }
    }
  }
}

PUT example10022021
GET example10022021
```

> In this GET API response you can see "ignore_above" parameter in mappings

```
PUT /example/_mappings
{
    "properties": {
      "SomeID": {
        "type": "keyword",
        "store":true,
        "eager_global_ordinals":true
      }
    }
}
```

Now again

```
GET example10022021
```

> Now you can see in the response that  "ignore_above" parameter is
> NOT present

Comment: Can you share the commands you've run so we can reproduce the issue?

Comment: @Val Thanks for reaching out! I have updated the question with API I have tried, can you please help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's correct, for the same reason you need to re-specify `store: true` otherwise the update doesn't work (because it would take the default value which is `false`), you also need to re-specify `ignore_above: 5`:

So you can do it like this:

```
PUT /example/_mappings
{
    "properties": {
      "SomeID": {
        "type": "keyword",
        "store":true,
        "ignore_above": 5,
        "eager_global_ordinals":true
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Val ! but this doesn't seem to be a feasible solution, as I will have to keep track of all the previous mappings, and if I forget to mention even one of them, then it will go back to default value, isn't there any way or hack? or is this the only solution?

Comment: What I don't understand is why don't you set that in the original template to make sure that the index gets created correctly, instead of patching the mapping after the fact. Can you explain why you need to do it in two steps?

Comment: For Ex: I have a client, having a large data that needs to be indexed, so client specifies, lets say "ignore_above", but as the requirements keeps changing, client realizes that the "eager_global_ordinals" also has to be there, but this time client doesn't have the knowledge(or may accidently) that if it doesn't specify the prev mapping parameters they will get overrides with default values, and update the mappings, then it will cause the change in behavior, that why I wanted to find out a way

Comment: In my opinion, if you let your clients mess with their indexes, they should at least know how it works and what they are doing, otherwise they should rely on someone who knows. Otherwise you're up for a big mess. The whole purpose of index templates is to be able to change the mapping for the next index to be created, so instead of changing existing index mappings, they should simply change the index template and then create a new index and/or roll over to a new index

Comment: Hello @val, can you please have a look at this question, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66797606/disable-dynamic-mapping-completely-in-elasticsearch