# Disable dynamic mapping completely in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack

I have an index template, from which I am creating an index

```
PUT /_index_template/example_template
{
   "index_patterns": [
        "example*"
    ],
    "priority": 1,
    "template": {
        "aliases": {
            "example":{}
        },
    "mappings": {
"dynamic":strict,
      "_source":
      {"enabled": false},
      "properties": {
       "SomeID":
        { "type": "keyword", "index" : true,"store":true,"ignore_above":5},
       "firstName":
        { "type": "text", "index" : true,"store":true},
        "lastName":
        { "type": "text", "index" : false},
        "PersonInfo": {
        "type": "object",
"dynamic":"true",
        "properties": {
          "FirstName": {
            "type": "keyword",
            "index": true,
            "store": false
          }
        }
        }
      }
    },
    "settings": {
    "index": {
      "number_of_shards": 1,  
      "number_of_replicas": 3
    }
  }
  }
}
```

As in the template mappings you can see I am making the dynamic as Strict, so that new fields cant be added to the mappings,
while on inner object, PersonInfo, I can set dynamic as true, which takes precedence and allow to insert a new field mapping.

```
PUT example10022021/_doc/1
{
   "SomeID":"1234",
   "firstName":"Nishikant",
   "PersonInfo.service_data":"random"
}
```

Here service_data is getting added into mappings, as dynamic is true

```
"PersonInfo" : {
          "dynamic" : "true",
          "properties" : {
            "FirstName" : {
              "type" : "keyword"
            },
            "service_data" : {
              "type" : "text",
              "fields" : {
                "keyword" : {
                  "type" : "keyword",
                  "ignore_above" : 256
                }
              }
            }
          }
```

Is there any way to disable the dynamic mapping completely? like specifying globally?

Thanks!

Steps I took After @Val answer:

```
PUT /_index_template/example_template
{
   "index_patterns": [
        "example*"
    ],
    "priority": 1,
    "template": {
        "aliases": {
            "order":{}
        },
    "mappings": {
      "dynamic": "strict",
      "dynamic_templates": [
        {
          "objects": {
            "match_mapping_type": "object",
            "mapping": {
              "dynamic": "strict"
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "_source":
      {"enabled": false},
      "properties": {
       "BillToID":
        { "type": "keyword", "index" : true,"store":true,"ignore_above":5},
       "firstName":
        { "type": "text", "index" : true,"store":true},
        "lastName":
        { "type": "text", "index" : false},
        "PersonInfo": {
        "type": "object",
        "dynamic":true,
        "properties": {
          "FirstName": {
            "type": "keyword",
            "index": true,
            "store": false
          }
        }
        }
      }
    },
    "settings": {
    "index": {
      "number_of_shards": 1,  
      "number_of_replicas": 3
    }
  }
  }
}
```

then I create an index

```
PUT example10022021
```

then inserting a document

```
POST example10022021/_doc/1
{
   "BillToID":"1234",
   "firstName":"Nishikant",
   "PersonInfo.service_data":"random"
}
```

this will result in 200OK, now if you check the mappings again

```
GET example10022021
```

in o/p you can see the dynamic field mapping getting added(this behavior I don't want),

```
"PersonInfo" : {
          "dynamic" : "true",
          "properties" : {
            "FirstName" : {
              "type" : "keyword"
            },
            "service_data" : {
              "type" : "text",
              "fields" : {
                "keyword" : {
                  "type" : "keyword",
                  "ignore_above" : 256
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you can do is to create another index template that applies to all indexes, i.e. using the `*` name pattern:

```
PUT /_index_template/common_template
{
   "index_patterns": [
        "*"
    ],
    "priority": 0,
    "template": {
       "mappings": {
         "dynamic": "strict",
         ...
```

If you want to also restrict the creation of dynamic fields inside inner objects, you can leverage [dynamic templates](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/dynamic-templates.html), like this:

```
PUT /_index_template/common_template
{
  "index_patterns": [
    "*"
  ],
  "priority": 1000,
  "template": {
    "settings": {},
    "mappings": {
      "dynamic": "strict",
      "dynamic_templates": [
        {
          "objects": {
            "match_mapping_type": "object",
            "mapping": {
              "dynamic": "strict"
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "properties": {
        "test": {
          "type": "object",
          "properties": {
            "inner": {
              "type": "integer"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

With the above index template, you can create a document like this one:

```
POST test/_doc/
{
  "test": {
    "inner": 1
  }
}
```

But not like this one:

```
POST test/_doc/
{
  "test": {
    "inner": 1,
    "inner2": 2        <--- this will not be allowed
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reaching out! I tried as you said @Val, but still I was able to add a new document with field, which is not originally present in my index template mappings, and those field mappings are getting added, as I have set dynamic as true, on inner object level, but I dont want this behavior, I want the dynamic strict to be applied to all objects or like index level dynamic mappings taking highest precedence, instead of inner object

Comment: I am using ES 7.10 and I have updated the question with more details

Comment: I follow up with your API, and it working, but when I provide "test": {
          "type": "object","dynamic": true,..here this inner level dynamic is taking preference, and adding a new field to the mappings

Comment: Of course, when creating an index directly with `PUT index`, if you provide a mappings section, it will always take precedence over the templates

Comment: No, I am not creating new index with PUT index, I am just creating index template, with dynamic template as you provided, just added dynamic=true on test object and then making a POST test/_doc/1{"test":"inner": 1,
    "inner2": 2 }..here the inner2 is getting added as field mapping, so its not following the strict from dynamic template, but dynamic as true as specified.

Comment: Can you update your question with an exact reproduction of what you're doing?

Comment: I have updated the question with steps I took while trying your solution

Comment: What I don't get is why do you specify `"dynamic":true,` in `PersonInfo`? This will override everything else

Comment: as I have a client, they may pass the dynamic:true, but I wanted to append the dynamic:strict on mapping level, so that dynamic field mapping is not allowed? so as you are suggesting there is no other way, I will need to parse the JSON and remove the dynamic on inner object level? or is there any?

Comment: Indeed, if your client can pass whatever he wants, he will always override the defaults set in your template. So you need to apply some cleansing, and it's also a good practice

Comment: Thanks @Val, I appreciate all the help!

Comment: It would be really helpful if you can help me with this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67414496/how-to-restrict-a-field-in-elasticsearch-document-to-be-updated, Thanks!