# How to restrict a field in Elasticsearch document to be updated?

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack

I have an Elasticsearch index, I am saving document into the index.

Is there any way, when I try to index/save same document(with same _id) again, with new value/updated value for some field,
Elasticsearch should throw an exception,

> only if that particular field is what we are trying to update? for other field it can work as default behavior.

For Ex: I have index mapping as below

```
PUT /_index_template/example_template
{
   "index_patterns": [
        "example*"
    ],
    "priority": 1,
    "template": {
        "aliases": {
            "example":{}
        },
    "mappings": {
      "dynamic":"strict",
      "_source":
      {"enabled": false},
      "properties": {
        "SomeID": {
        "type": "keyword"
      },
      "AnotherInfo": {
        "type": "keyword"
      }
    }
  }
  }
}
```

Then I create an index based on this index mapping

```
PUT example01
```

After that I save a document against the this index

```
POST example01/_doc/1
{
  "SomeId": "abcdedf",
  "AnotherInfo":"xyze"
}
```

Now next time if I try to save the document again with different "SomeId" value

```
POST example01/_doc/1
    {
      "SomeId": "uiiuiiu",
      "AnotherInfo":"xyze"
    }
```

I want to say "Sorry "someId" field can not be updated"

> basically, Preventing document field from getting updated in Elastic
> Search.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Elastic search support revision on documents by default it meant it trace the changes on indexed documents with their generated _id and each time you manipulate the document for example with id 17 it's increase the value of @Version field so you can not have two duplicated document with same id if you don't have custom_routing but if you have custom routing always be careful about duplication on _id field because this field is not just identifier it's also keep record of which shard it located.

More over i guess elastic has no way to enforce restrictions at the field level within a document and you may control restriction on updating fields on application level or field level security based on roles.

As an example of field level security consider below role definition grants read access only to the category, @timestamp, and message fields in all the events-* data streams and indices.

```html
POST /_security/role/test_role1
{
  "indices": [
    {
      "names": [ "events-*" ],
      "privileges": [ "read" ],
      "field_security" : {
        "grant" : [ "category", "@timestamp", "message" ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: thanks for replying, I have updated the question with more detail, basically is there any parameter that we can set while providing mappings or any other way to restrict update to particular field, after it is indexed?

Comment: Great, Now i upvoted your question !, I guess  elastic has no way to enforce restrictions at the field level and you should manage restriction at application level. Read more on here 
 https://discuss.elastic.co/t/preventing-document-field-from-getting-updated-in-elastic-search/234300

Comment: Thanks for the upvote! In the link you mentioned, they are saying that it can be done using https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/field-level-security.html? is that right?

Comment: yes it is ,you might control it in your application level and not database field level.

Comment: I have also edited the answer related to your question edit .

Comment: Thanks! I tried the field level security feature and it is only available for platinum users:(,